# How do I get tailwindcss intellisense for VSCode to work with MUI's slotProps?

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css, intellisense

I'm trying to customize MUI components in an existing project with tailwindcss, as shown e.g. here: https://mui.com/base-ui/guides/working-with-tailwind-css/#create-the-slider-component

```
import { Slider as BaseSlider, SliderProps } from "@mui/base/Slider";
import * as React from "react";

const Slider = React.forwardRef(function Slider(
  props: SliderProps,
  ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLSpanElement>,
) {
  return (
    <BaseSlider
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      slotProps={{
        thumb: {
          className:
            "ring-cyan-500 dark:ring-cyan-400 ring-2 w-4 h-4 -mt-1 -ml-2 flex items-center justify-center bg-white rounded-full shadow absolute",
        },
        root: { className: "w-full relative inline-block h-2 cursor-pointer" },
        rail: {
          className:
            "bg-slate-100 dark:bg-slate-700 h-2 w-full rounded-full block absolute",
        },
        track: {
          className: "bg-cyan-500 dark:bg-cyan-400 h-2 absolute rounded-full",
        },
      }}
    />
  );
});

export default Slider;
```

I have [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) installed in my VSCode, which works for `className`:

[image]

However, I get no intellisense with the nested `className`s inside of MUI's `slotProps` prop:

[image]

Is there any way to get intellisense working here? My relevant configs look like this:

```json
// settings.json
{
  // ...
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": "on"
  }
}
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came close to an answer by adding the following to my `settings.json`:

```json
// settings.json
{
  // ...
  "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
    "className\\:.*?['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]"
  ]
}
```

This does not work for long class lists which are split across multiple lines, e.g.

```js
      slotProps={{
        rail: {
          className:
            "bg-slate-100 dark:bg-slate-700 h-2 w-full rounded-full block absolute",
        },
      }}
```

I have tried to get the regex to span multiple lines, but it doesn't seem possible at the moment.